# Page selector (block development)

Tags: concrete5

In Concrete 5.6 it was possible to create a JavaScript callback. I would like to know how this can be achieved in 5.7. I want to select a page and then do an ajax call to get the area names from that page.

I took al look at the core files and the option for the callback does not exist anymore. I have used the js method to create the page selector.

```
<div data-field="entry-link-page-selector" class="form-group">
   <label><?php echo t('Choose Page:') ?></label>
    <div data-field="entry-link-page-selector-select"></div>
</div>

<script>

$('div[data-field=entry-link-page-selector-select]').concretePageSelector({
    'inputName': 'cTargetID'
});
```

Old way

```
<?php echo $page_selector->selectPage('cTargetID', $cTargetID, 'pageChange'); ?>
```

-- update --
In the add.php and edit.php I include form.php. In this file I use the page_selector and the js to bind to the event. Still the event does not trigger the alert for some reason. I used the example as given in the answer below.

```
<?php
defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die (_("Acccess Denied"));

$al = Core::make('helper/concrete/asset_library');
$colorPicker = Core::make('helper/form/color');
$pageSelect= Core::make('helper/form/page_selector');
?>

<style>
    .ccm-hide{display:none;}
</style>

<div class="subbscribe-form">

    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $pageSelect->selectPage('displayPagesCID', $displayPagesCID); ?>
    </div>

</div>


<script>
    Concrete.event.bind('SitemapSelectPage', function(e, data) {
        alert('You selected "' + data.title + '", it\'s cID is ' + data.cID);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 7, concrete5 added things called "events". You can see all of the events that are fired when you select a page by opening your developer console and running `Concrete.event.debug(true)`. Once you find the event you want to use, you can hook into it by using `Concrete.event.bind` for example:

```javascript
Concrete.event.bind('SomeEvent', function(e, data) {
    // Do Stuff.
});
```

The event that you're going to want to hook into is `SitemapSelectPage`, it gives supplies the `cID`, `title`, and the sitemap instance.

**EDIT:** Due to a current core bug, the `SitemapSelectPage` event bindings get cleared just before the dialog opens, to get around this we just bind to the `ConcreteSitemap` event and bind there.

Here's a working example:

```javascript
Concrete.event.bind('ConcreteSitemap', function(e, instance) {

    Concrete.event.bind('SitemapSelectPage', function(e, data) {
        if (data.instance == instance) {
            Concrete.event.unbind(e);

            alert("You've selected a page! " + data.cID);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thx. Very nice to know I can bind in to events. However I am still not enable to retrieve the selected pageID.  I updated the question with the results.

Comment: You should log the content of "data", it should contain some useful information.

Comment: Make sure to vote up and select the proper answer when your solution is found.

Comment: I used our example in the auto.js of my block. The alert triggers when I edit the block. But when I select a page it does not trigger again. Seems strange to me since you can see the event is fired via de debug(true). In the autonav block they use this bind event as well. I will try to see how they got it working.

Comment: Raverix pointed out that the first argument is the event, not the data. You can see all the arguments passed by running `console.log(arguments)`.

Comment: I am sorry but I still can't get it to work. The console.log / alert do not get triggered. I have updated the example.  Maybe you can spot the fault? Thx again.

Comment: You're calling publish,  it needs to be `bind`.

Comment: I used bind you saw the wrong example. I removed the first update so it is more clear.

Comment: I've updated my answer to work with the current core.

Comment: Thx allot. This work you only need to fix var instance = data. since data is not defined. I did var instance = instance.

Comment: Yeah, didn't mean to leave that in there. You can just remove it as I did in my edit.

Answer (score -1):

I confirm that the option for the callback is gone which is a bummer frankly but you can easily do it yourself I think with a little bit of javascript.

```
<?php echo $page_selector->selectPage('cTargetID', $cTargetID); ?>
<script>
$('input[name=cTargetID]').on('change', function() {
    // Do something here
});
</script>
```

Edit: this doesn't work as the whole selector is removed and re-added through js so the change event is never triggered.
Unfortunately I wasn't able to find an alternate solution

Comment: Yes you're right. After looking at the code I see the whole node containing the field is deleted and replaced with a different node with a field with the same name so the change event isn't triggered.

So far I wasn't able to figure out a solution. If I do, I'll make sure to let you know